# Generate Uppercase Table names using Spring JPA for Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get the records from postgres using Spring Jpa. All the tables and columns in Postgres are in uppercase but spring jpa generates the queries in lower case eventhough I have mentioned the table name in upper case in the entity class. I have gone through lot of posts on stackoverflow on this similar issue and everyone suggests to add the naming-strategy to the yaml file which I did but still the table name is generated in lowercase. I've used the below strategies(each at a time but nothing worked for me). Am I missing something else?

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

```
Caused by: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "**table_name**" does not exist**
  Position: 258
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 179 common frames omitted
```

Here's the properties I've added to my yaml file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

        #hibernate.naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        #hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        #hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Did you try using `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` or simply put table names in quotes?

Comment: Another good example why you should not use quoted identifiers. Why did you create the tables with upper case names in the first place? If you had never quoted them, you would not have run into this problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I did it on purpose becuase I am populating/loading data from Kafka using Sink Connectors and the Schema registry in kafka is not recognizing the table or column names if they are in lowercase because schema-registry is created in uppercase by default.

Comment: @Daria: No i did not add "globally_quoted_identifiers" to my properties. After adding this, the table name is in uppercase but maybe postgres is expecting the table name to be inside quotes. I get the error: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: **Unable to find column with logical name: COLUMN_NAME in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(schema.TABLE_NAME) and its related supertables and secondary tables** ...... In postgres DB when i run keeping table name inside quotes it works, if no quotes then it is not working. Select * from schema."TABLENAME" (If the query is this way it works)

Comment: @AlfaRomeo How did you create your tables? If without quotes, table and column names are force-lowercased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced what you need in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE temp."SOME_UPPERCASE_TABLE" (
  dt      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  column1 VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_UPPERCASE_TABLE", schema = "tmp", catalog = "cram")
public class SomeUppercaseTableEntity {
    private Timestamp dt;
    private String column1;
    // getters, setters...
```

Everything works well.

Comment: This requires `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` as well, otherwise quoting for the upper-name in `@Table` won't apply. Without that setting, it would need to be `@Table(name = "\"SOME_UPPERCASE_TABLE\"", [...])` to by-pass Postgres' case-folding to lower-case.